# What is the best way to send what the customer ordered in the payment intent?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

In [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart), the docs teach how to use stripe with react + express.

I'm currently using the field `metadata` to put a JSON string with the order detail so that the webhook can know what the user ordered:

```
await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      currency: "brl",
      amount: getTotal(orderItems),
      payment_method_types: ["card", "boleto"],
      receipt_email: userEmail,
      description: getSummary(orderItems),
      metadata: {
        userId,
        reports: getReportMetadata(orderItems),
      },
    });
```

But stripe put a limit of 500 characters in this field. To prevent some edge case buy orders from being blocked, I transform each field of the JSON array in a one-letter word before sending to this function. But it seems that this is not the right field to do it. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a length limitation on that field. You can consider splitting your information into multiple fields, or save your information into your own DB and only save a reference ID into metadata. Later on you can take the reference ID and query your DB for full/concrete information you need.

Note that [Metadata is a dictionary type](https://stripe.com/docs/videos/developer-foundations?video=metadata).